# api gateway showing post request, while lambda showing any

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I changed the method from any to post in api gateway for an endpoint

[image]

but in my lambda the trigger details show its any method

[image]

Why lambda is not reflecting as POST

Comment: Could it be that you didn't restrict the method inside the policy?